# CMIS unit tests?

Tags: cmis

These days, many companies and open source groups implement [CMIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services) servers, striving to comply with the [specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.0/cmis-spec-v1.0.html).

I am also developing a CMIS server.

**QUESTION:** Where can I find readily usable unit tests for my CMIS server?

For now the best unit tests seem to be offered by [Alfresco](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS#AtomPub_TCK), but I would like to hear about any other. Especially open source ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Apache Chemistry](http://chemistry.apache.org/) has a CMIS TCK. The easiest way to run it is to download the [CMIS Workbench](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/tools/dev-tools-workbench.html) and press the TCK button. All TCK tests are also JUnit tests.

Comment: Thanks! If I understand well, Alfresco donated those tests to Apache.